# regex word boundaries+quotes

Tags: python, regex

I have the following expression that should match the entire given word in case insensitive way.Quotes are part of the word so I check whether the word is preceded or followed by any quote. For example, the word "foo" shouldn't  match the text "foo's".

```
word = "foo"
pattern = re.compile(r'(?<![a-z\'])%s(?![a-z\'])' % word,flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

The exception are triple quotes, if the word is inside(next to) the triple quotes it should match:

```
pattern.search("'''foo bar baz'''")
```

"foo" should be found this time but it doesn't because the word is preceded by a quote.

Comment: XD, my regex should find the word if it's inside the triple quotes but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
((?<![a-z\'\"])|(?<=\'{3}))foo((?![a-z\'\"])|(?=\'{3}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex `(?:(?<=''')|(?<!'))\bfoo\b(?:(?=''')|(?!'))`

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?:(?<=\'\'\')|(?<!\'))\b%s\b(?:(?=\'\'\')|(?!\'))' % word,flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using lookahead:

```
>>> pat = r'([\'\"]{3}|\b)foo\1'
>>> m = re.search(pat, 'My """foo""" is rich')
>>> re.search(pat, 'My """foo""" is rich').groups()
('"""',)
>>> re.search(pat, "My '''foo''' is rich").groups()
("'''",)
>>> re.search(pat, 'My """foo"" is rich').groups()
('',)
>>> re.search(pat, 'My """foo\'\'\' is rich').groups()
('',)
```